# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference please help me with this error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

Can someone help me about this error? "    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference"

and it keeps saying my error is around this line -->
if (searchRiderMowdel.getusername().equals(textViewValue))

and I tried some methods and it keeps crashing as usual

```
public class EmployeeUserFragment extends Fragment {

Button btnPlot;
ImageButton Searchemployee;

Redirectinglog redirectinglog;
@BindView(R.id.Searchemployee) AutoCompleteTextView autoTextValue;
Api api;
private Handler searchHandler = new Handler();
ArrayList<String> employeename;
TextView latitudesearch,longitudesearch,Fullnamesearch, gpssearch, departsearch, Idsearch, emailsearch;


public EmployeeUserFragment() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employeeuser, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    autoTextValue = view.findViewById(R.id.Searchemployee);
    btnPlot = view.findViewById(R.id.btnPlot);
    Searchemployee  = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    employeename = new ArrayList<>();
    api = RetrofitClientInstance.GetResultAPI().create(Api.class);


    Call<List<EmployeeName>> employeelistcall = api.getemploeyeename();

    employeelistcall.enqueue(new Callback<List<EmployeeName>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<EmployeeName>> call, Response<List<EmployeeName>> response) {

            if(!response.isSuccessful()){

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            List<EmployeeName> autoCompleteModelList = response.body();

            for (EmployeeName completeModel : autoCompleteModelList){

                String employeenamelist = "";

                employeenamelist += completeModel.getusername();

                employeename.add(employeenamelist);

            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> newAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, employeename);

            autoTextValue.setAdapter(newAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<EmployeeName>> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    redirectinglog = new Redirectinglog(getActivity());

    btnPlot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (latitudesearch.length() == 0 && longitudesearch.length() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Update Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });


    Searchemployee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hideSoftKeyboard(getActivity());
            getEmployeeLocation();
            employeeRunnable.run();
        }
    });

}

private Runnable employeeRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getEmployeeLocation();
        searchHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
};

private void getEmployeeLocation(){
    Call<List<employeesearchcoordinate>> riderInformationCall = api.getemployeecoordinate();

    riderInformationCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<employeesearchcoordinate>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<employeesearchcoordinate>> call, Response<List<employeesearchcoordinate>> response) {

            if(!response.isSuccessful()){

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            List<employeesearchcoordinate> riderModelList = response.body();

            String textViewValue = autoTextValue.getText().toString().trim();

            if (textViewValue.equals("")){

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No value detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            else{

                for (employeesearchcoordinate searchRiderMowdel : riderModelList){

                    if (searchRiderMowdel.getusername().equals(textViewValue)){

                        Fullnamesearch.setText(searchRiderMowdel.getgps_id());
                        latitudesearch.setText(searchRiderMowdel.getRTLatitude());
                        longitudesearch.setText(searchRiderMowdel.getRTLongitude());
                        gpssearch.setText(searchRiderMowdel.getRTNumber());
                        departsearch.setText(searchRiderMowdel.getRTdevice_dep());
                        Idsearch.setText(searchRiderMowdel.getRTcard_uid());
                        emailsearch.setText(searchRiderMowdel.getRTemail());


                    }

                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<employeesearchcoordinate>> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}



public void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity){
    if (activity.getCurrentFocus() == null){
        return;
    }
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

}

Comment: Then, getusername() or textViewValue is null, try to print inside for cycle.

Comment: What do you mean? :/

Comment: In your if there are two strings to compare. This error tell you that first string or second string is null. Try to use Log.d("string1", searchRiderMowdel.getusername()) and Log.d("string2",textViewValue) before your if.

Comment: @FrancescoBocci Specifically, that the first (`searchRidermowdel.getusername()`) is null. If the second was null, that'd just resolve to false, not throw NPE.

Comment: it says android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:168)

Comment: @rzwitserloot how do i solve it?

Comment: @ZovericSama make sure that getusername() doesn't return null. Alternatively, save that to a variable first, and write an `if (that == null)`  check.

Comment: actually thank you @rzwitserloot  I solved it. Ye like u said getusername is null.